# Near location with lat and long

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation, gps, location

I Want Compare my Current latitude & longitude to another latitude & longitude and found near location to me
how can i calculate this ?

```
my location : 
51.510836, -0.127579

another : 

51.547385, 0.020022
51.482876, -0.036542
51.511894, -0.248477
```

Comment: post your tried code.

Comment: @Priyal i dont know how can i found near location but my language is php or javascript i want calculate algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i understand
you problem is to get closest location via lat long

And you want to calculate which one is closest from your location

if yes then one by one compare all these 3 lat, long with your location's lat long.
The nearest location is which one has lowest distance in km.
try this.

```
    function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

where lat1, lon1 is your location and lat2,lon2 are those points you wanna compare simply apply it in loop and pass compared locations and finally a distance which is lowest is your answer.